# Как выполнить поиск и копирование данных в Excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Пытаюсь освоить хоть что-нибудь (openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlrd-xlwt...) что поможет мне выполнить следующий, казалось бы простой алгоритм:

1. Открыть Excel файл.
2. Найти в определенном столбце ячейку совпадающую с заранее заданным словом (на русском языке).
3. Скопировать всю строку вместе с этой ячейкой и всеми данными в этой строке (ряду).
4. Создать новый файл Excel и записать туда все это (все ряды, в которых нашлось то заранее заданное слово).

Попробовал ровно каждый из модулей. В одних жуткие траблы с получением данных из строки, другие не воспринимают русский язык в ячейках, третьи вообще отказываются работать.

Вот допустим, последний неудавшийся пример с использованием `win32com`:

```
import win32com.client
Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

text = 'Блендер'
counter = 2

def write(val, pos):
    wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add()
    ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    i = 1
    for rec in val:
        ws.Cells(pos,i).value = rec
        i = i + 1
    wb.SaveAs('test.xlsx')
    wb.Close()
    Excel.Quit()


def search():
    wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(u'C:/Users/User/Desktop/excel.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.ActiveSheet
    srch = [r[0].value for r in sheet.Range("B2:B13")]
    for items in srch:
        if text in items:
            global counter
            print ('Found')
            found = sheet.Range("A%s:D%s" % (counter,counter)).Value
            print (found)
            write(found,counter)
        counter += 1
    
search()
```

Наверняка этот код настолько неидеален, насколько это вообще возможно.
Но пусть там будет хоть овер999 костылей, лишь бы работало, а он не работает даже с этим - при виде русскоязычного текста впадает истерику и кричит 'OLE error NONE NONE'. А даже без русских символов один фиг записывает только первую ячейку.

Буду бесконечно рад любой помощи.

Comment: вы можете залить (http://www.filedropper.com/) пример вашего Excel фйла и выложить сюда ссылку на него?

Comment: @MaxU к сожалению на filedropper'e используется флэш. Вот тоже хороший сервис http://dropmefiles.com/605137

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

```
In [155]: text = 'Смеситель'

In [156]: df[df.ix[:,1].str.lower().str.contains(text.lower())]
Out[156]:
    № товара Наименование товара  Цена товара Страна производитель
5          6     Смеситель VITEK         5000               РОССИЯ
9         10     Смеситель Rivex        11000             СЛОВЕНИЯ
11        12  Смеситель Tragefar         7000               РОССИЯ
```

Вот решение, использующее Pandas модуль:

```
import pandas as pd

text = 'blender'

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\temp\.data\excel.xlsx')
df[df.ix[:,1].str.lower().str.contains(text.lower())].to_excel('d:/temp/result.xlsx', index=False)
```

PS для Python 2.x стоит воспользоваться `unicode_literals` или декодировать строку:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

или

```
df[df.ix[:,1].str.lower().str.contains(text.decode('utf-8').lower())]
```

Demo (Python 3.5):

```
In [133]: import pandas as pd

In [134]: text = 'blender'

In [135]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\excel.xlsx'

In [136]: df = pd.read_excel(fn)

In [137]: df
Out[137]:
    № товара          Наименование товара  Цена товара Страна производитель
0          1            Кондиционер VITEK        22000                КИТАЙ
1          2            Мультиварка Tefal         8000             СЛОВЕНИЯ
2          3                 Blender BEKO         4000               ЯПОНИЯ
3          4   Микроволновая печь Redmond         3800                КИТАЙ
4          5           Сплит-система BEKO        25000                КИТАЙ
5          6              Смеситель VITEK         5000               РОССИЯ
6          7              Blender Messimo         9000                  США
7          8          Мультиварка Redmond         3000               РОССИЯ
8          9  Микроволновая печь Smithson        19000                КИТАЙ
9         10              Смеситель Rivex        11000             СЛОВЕНИЯ
10        11             Blender SmithPRO        14000               ЯПОНИЯ
11        12           Смеситель Tragefar         7000               РОССИЯ
```

фильтруем по второй (в Python/Pandas нумерация начинается с `0`, поэтому вторая колонка имеет индекс: `1`) колонке

```
In [138]: df[df.ix[:,1].str.lower().str.contains(text.lower())]
Out[138]:
    № товара Наименование товара  Цена товара Страна производитель
2          3        Blender BEKO         4000               ЯПОНИЯ
6          7     Blender Messimo         9000                  США
10        11    Blender SmithPRO        14000               ЯПОНИЯ

In [139]: df[df.ix[:,1].str.lower().str.contains(text)].to_excel('d:/temp/result.xlsx', index=False)
```

result.xlsx:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS самый быстрый и простой способ установки Pandas - установить [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), который уже включает в себя все необходимые модули для анализа и обработки данных: NumPy, SciPy, sklearn, Pandas и [многое другое](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Но есть недостаток, забыл вернуть назад - я в исходном файле блендер переименовал на blender ради теста, в оригинале так и есть Блендер на русском. Попробовал ваш скрипт - по русским названиям не ищет :( Есть какой-то выход из этой ситуации?

Comment: Спасибо!!! Если вам несложно - подскажите как еще можно добавить поиск по нескольким словам и вывод их группами по названиям, разделяя пустым рядом, так как глядя на такой код даже идей нет :(

Comment: вот этого не понял: `вывод их группами по названиям, разделяя пустым рядом` - можете привести пример в виде текста в [вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/569340/edit)?

Comment: почему-то главный пост не правится ("произошла ошибка", хм). Вот ссылка на картинку с примером http://f4.s.qip.ru/18qb6SzE.png

Comment: т.е. вам фильтровать строки не надо? надо просто сгрупировать по названиям и разделить пустой строкой?

Comment: Получается да. Ну в идеале должно быть вот как на картинке, если совсем в идеале - еще и по странам разбивать иметь возможность :-).

Comment: предлагаю перенести кодирование "идеала" в отдельный вопрос, т.к. ответ и так уже перегружен... ;)

Comment: [Вот темка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569358/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-excel-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-python)