# Как выполнить группировку данных в Excel?

Tags: python, excel

Исходный [Excel файл](http://dropmefiles.com/605137).

Неплохо бы сделать поиск по нескольким словам и вывод их группами по названиям, разделяя пустым рядом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: так фильтрование нужно или нет?

Comment: @MaxU ну смотря что под этим подразумевается. Фильтрование по странам - было бы очень неплохо.

Comment: фильтрование это выбор по каким-то критериям. в результате строк становится меньше. в вашем примере все данные присутствуют, поэтому не совсем понятно что имелось в виду под: `поиск по нескольким словам...`

Comment: @MaxU Похоже фильтрование я понял не в том ключе. Это все-таки лишнее. А под "по нескольким словам" я тогда написал какую-то глупость. В любом случае самый крутой вариант - это пример на картинке, единственное что там страны вразброс в группах (а хотелось бы в алфавитном порядке :), но это не обязательно).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\temp\.data\excel.xlsx').sort_values('Страна производитель')

empty_row = pd.DataFrame({'a':['']})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'd:/temp/result.xlsx')

count = 0

for k,g in df.groupby(df['Наименование товара'].str.extract(r'(\w+)\s+', expand=False)):
    g.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=(count==0), 
               startrow=count+(count!=0))
    count += len(g) + 1
    empty_row.to_excel(writer, header=None, index=False, startrow=count)

writer.save()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обалдеть, вы мой герой!

Comment: Буду теперь учить pandas. И еще - скиньте мне свой номерок как-нибудь, я вам на пиво\сок закину за такую работу :)

Comment: Спасибо, на пиво я себе сам заработаю ;)

Comment: Доволен как слон :-)! Все прекрасно работает и сильно облегчает работу нескольким людям. Можно еще один вопросик? Обещаю что последний и больше не буду Вас отвлекать:). Оказалось, что в графе "Наименование товара" не все товары идут с названия прибора. То есть прибор может быть как "Мультиварка Tefal" так и "Tefal Мультиварка" и "433-Z Мультиварка Tefal". И получается, что все ряды с названием начинающимся не с "Мультиварка...", когда выполняется поиск по "мультиварка" выпадают в отдельную группу, где сбиваются все сорта оборудования не попадающие под маску. Можно советик по решению?

Comment: @S.Stuart, в этом случае нужен либо какой-либо RegEx который сможет вычленить название (Мультиварка, Блендер, ...) из строки либо иметь полный список всех возможных наименований... Если выложите такой список, то поменять код несложно

Comment: @S.Stuart, можно вести такой список в CSV или в Excel файле...

Comment: Простите, я немного не понял. Всех возможных наименований ? Ну то есть это имеется ввиду просто список всевозможных типов товаров (мультиварка, блендер, смеситель...) или просто столбец с исходными наименованиями? Если последнее - вот из реального примера http://dropmefiles.com/887243. Если первое - это в принципе возможно, но составление такого списка займет довольно продолжительное время, так как товаров много и они каждый раз разные. Может можно выделять из строки только русские символы, ибо все что кроме них - это или модель товара или марка, что не является приоритетным при отборе.

Comment: Но наверное просто выделение русских слов (если это вообще возможно) не подойдет, так как если попадется модель с русским названием, то снова выделит отдельно. Но я думаю таких случаев будет мало.

Comment: @S.Stuart, да нужен список по типу: `['мультиварка', 'блендер', 'смеситель']` - т.е. по тем словам, по которым вы хотите групировать товары. Иначе вам придется придумывать искусственный интелект, чтобы угадывать наименования товаров... ;)

Comment: Эх.. Ну ладно, спасибо и на этом :)